Archive broken on Xcode 16 for React Native 0.75
I have a production app built with react native that has the iOS Archive broken after an upgrade.
This is a bare React Native project (not an expo project).
I upgraded the following:

react-native version to 0.75.4
Xcode to v16

So I'm not really sure which of those upgrades are causing the problem.
Running the app in debug mode works ok, however when archiving (in order to publish a new version of the app) it throws the error: 'EMFILE too many files open' and looking the full logs I see that comes from Metro.
That confuses me because as far as I know metro should not be running as part of the archive process, but this is fired from the react native scripts.
Any ideas?
I have tried to fix that Metro error by removing the line -reset-cache from react-native-xcode.sh and now it breaks in a different place. But I don't think touching the react native scripts is the way to go
